# How can I create a shortcut for firefox in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

How can I create a shortcut for Greasemonkey for the firefox bookmarks, or, a shortcut that opens a website?

Sorry,

I want a greasemonkey script that contain some script that bind some key for firefox bookmark

for example, press key 1 = open bookmark 1, and so on

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this fully... do you want dynamically generate a button an a greasemonkey-manipulated page for bookmarking something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I want a greasemonkey script that contain some script that bind some key for firefox bookmark

Here is an example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Google Shortcut
// @namespace      googleShortcut
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // pressed alt+g
  if (e.keyCode == 71 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
   window.location = "http://google.com"; // go to google.
  }
}, false);
})();
```

[This user script can be found at userscripts.org here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/80676).

This adds a "alt+g" hotkey to all pages which when pressed will take the user to google.com.

[This is a very good document explaining how to hook on to different hotkeys, providing all of the keycodes, and information about cross platforms quirks, etc](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

You'll have to [read this documentation on Greasemonkey to learn how to customize the header information](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).

Then just save the file with a `.user.js` extension, and drag and drop it to a Firefox window to install it. When your done upload it to [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org) in case someone else would like the script.